# Vim record history

Tags: vim

Vim stores the list of commands that we applied using : for the current execution.
But when I close vim and start it again, the vim command history is lost.
I tried `set history = 1000` in the .vimrc file but that did not help. 
Where does Vim maintain the local command history? 
What is the command to retain command history?

Comment: Works fine on my system, what version of vim are you running?

Comment: its working fine on my desktio system .. version 7.3 but it does not work on my lappy. even that version is 7.3 i guess

Comment: I just checked my `.vimrc`, there's no setting regarding command history… saving history seems to be the default.

Comment: you may need to check  $HOME/.viminfo file. it keeps command history in it.

Comment: question is how do I make sure it is not getting erased for new execution of vim ??

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To check whether Vim supports the `'viminfo'` file (which stores the history), `:echo has('viminfo')`. The corresponding setting must not be empty: `:set viminfo?`, and `:set history?` should be greater than one.

If there's a problem writing the viminfo file (though Vim should complain in that case), you could try passing a different location via `vim -i /tmp/viminfo`

Comment: it was weird that I didn't have the permission to write to `~/.viminfo` and vim didn't notify me.

Comment: wtf, my ~/.viminfo was root:root for absolutely no reason and vim was not complaining too!

Comment: @Ingo-Karkat, In my case, even though I have around 1500 command line commands in my `.viminfo`, `q:` shows only ~700 of them. I store titbits of commands in the command line history so I can reuse them without having to store them in another file. It usually works well.. I have checked that I have permissions for my `.viminfo` but still its not working. `history` is set to store the last `10000`. Any idea why this is not working, as expected?

Answer (score 78):

Just an issue that caught me out the other day, which may or may not be your problem:

On some Linux systems (e.g. Ubuntu), if the very first time you run VIM, you run it as a super-user, then the $HOME/.viminfo file gets created with root owner and your local user does not have permissions to write to it. This explained why my VIM was not storing command history when it was all configured up correctly.

Bottom line: on a *nix system, locate your .viminfo file, and make sure you have read/write permissions on it.

Answer (score 8):

You should check the permissions of the `.viminfo` file. You might need to change owner of the file to your current user using `chown` or `sudo chown`.

Comment: This was my problem. It defaulted to root.

Answer (score 6):

Mr. Baint has given the answer.

- Go to `$HOME` directory.
- give `ls -l .viminfo` to check permissions.
- change permission so that group and owner also can have write
  permission. use:

  ```
   sudo chown yourUserId $HOME/.viminfo
  ```

It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the viminfo option. Set it in your $MYVIMRC

**Update** To find out where the option was last set/changed:

```
:verbose set viminfo?
```

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#viminfo-file

> If you exit Vim and later start it again, you would normally lose a lot of
>   information.  The viminfo file can be used to remember that information, which
>   enables you to continue where you left off.
>
> This is introduced in section |21.3| of the user manual.
>
> The viminfo file is used to store:
>
> - The command line history.
> - The search string history.
> - The input-line history.
> - Contents of non-empty registers.
> - Marks for several files.
> - File marks, pointing to locations in files.
> - Last search/substitute pattern (for 'n' and '&').
> - The buffer list.
> - Global variables.
>
> The viminfo file is not supported when the |+viminfo| feature has been
>   disabled at compile time.

You could also use [`Session`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#Session) files.

Answer (score 0):

I went round in circles on this one a bit on Ubuntu and set viminfo solutions proposed above resulted in errors.

I eventually did the command "version" in the command mode and it came back with "-" for most stuff including:
-cmdline_hist 
-cmdline_info

I ran the following command and it all worked fine again:
sudo apt install vim

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue was that I had **vim-minimal** installed ([this is a default with Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Vim#:%7E:text=The%20vim%2Dminimal%20package%20comes%20pre%2Dinstalled%20on%20Fedora)), which does not support history. I had to uninstall it and install the full **vim** instead. I now have history... and syntaxic coloration !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a vimrc file, check your folders and files for existence and correctness

```
set history=200 
set undolevels=128 
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir/ 
set undofile 
set undolevels=1000 
set undoreload=10000
```

If the specified folder (undodir in my case) does not exist, the history will not be saved.